# about reading pin from register GPIODATA

Tags: c, embedded, bitwise-operators, gpio

I need to understand why i have to use **&=(and)** instead of **|=(or)**.

I tried drawing and using it but had no success.

```
      char readPin(char port,char pinNum){
       switch(port){
          case'A' :
              return ((portA &=(1<<pinNum))>>pinNum);
          case'B' :
              return ((portB &=(1<<pinNum))>>pinNum);
           case'C' :
              return ((portC &=(1<<pinNum))>>pinNum);
           case'D' :
              return ((portD &=(1<<pinNum))>>pinNum);
           case'E' :
              return ((portE &=(1<<pinNum))>>pinNum);
           case'F' :
              return ((portF &=(1<<pinNum))>>pinNum);

    }
}
```

I need to know why **and** is used instead of **or**.

Comment: Side-note: this is horrible code that might will cause multiple reads of the `volatile` port registers. Using `char` for bitwise arithmetic (or for that matter, for anything but holding strings) is naive, use `uint8_t` instead. And finally, don't left shift signed integer constants.

Comment: Fixed code should look something like this: https://godbolt.org/z/SyFRpW. Fixed the multiple volatile access bug and optimized it significantly.

Comment: I don't even understand, why for reading, you need to assign to the ports .. and it would be enough to shift right and only return the bit0 then .. `return (portX >> pinnum) & 1u;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 portA &=(1<<pinNum)
```

returns a '1' at the position shifted to.

For Example: PinNum = 4, Port A.4 is Set / High, Port A.1 is Set / High

```
PortA                           -    0001 0010
(1<<pinNum)                     -    0001 0000 &  // use bitwise and

portA &=(1<<pinNum)             -    0001 0000    // Result (bit 1 is discarded due to and operation)
((portA &=(1<<pinNum))>>pinNum) -    0000 0001    // Result is shifted back to position 0
```

The returned value is a 1.

If you were to use use a bitwise or like:

```
portA |= (1<<pinNum)
```

You would return a non 0 value in all cases.

For Example: PinNum = 4, all Port A bits are low.

```
PortA                           -    0000 0000
(1<<pinNum)                     -    0001 0000 |  // use bitwise or

portA |=(1<<pinNum)             -    0001 0000    // Result (bit 4 is set)
((portA |=(1<<pinNum))>>pinNum) -    0000 0001    // Result is shifted back to position 0
```

The returned value is a 1.

As you can see, you tried to check for Pin 4 (which is not set) but you got a non zero result back (caused the masking bit).

Comment: I understand thanks.
In the previous code IDE (code composer) need to add return value why ?

Comment: I do not understand your question.

Comment: You have a got a return value for each case!